# Android Programming with Java, how to use R.id

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio, r.java-file

studio to create an android app that adds a string from an editText with an id of input and displays it into `textView` with an id of output. But

```
EditText input = EditText(findViewById(R.id.input));
```

and

```
TextView output = TextView(findViewById(R.id.output));
```

doesnt work as it says Method call expected. Any kind of help would be great, thankyou.

```
package com.example.toshb.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Model model;
    public MainActivity() {model = new Model();}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void processInput(View view)
    {
        EditText input = EditText(findViewById(R.id.input));
        TextView output = TextView(findViewById(R.id.output));
        model.addString(editText.getText().toString());
        output.setText(model.getList());
        input.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add proper declaration of **EditText And TextView** . Before write a code please have a look here:
https://developer.android.com/index.html

```
EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
TextView output =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
model.addString(input.getText().toString());
```